# Duplicated data used in Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I'm having an issue in how data is being processed by the code below.  The data inputted is being processed from a main class and is held in an arraylist and processed through to this class.  The data is then sifted for the necessary information in parts of the array for mean averaging.

The data being inputted is coming into the code is 10hz so i should be expecting 200 inputs to be 20 seconds(ish).  What I am getting instead however, is several outputs of 200 inputs every second, which is making me think that it's the code itself that is duplicating or ticking too fast instead of waiting for the next input.  I have tried to search for aid in stopping duplications via SF but can't seem to find any.

I have tried to implement a timer to see if this counteracts the issue but it doesn't fix the issue and being new to java coding, I am not an expert and it's driving me a bit crazy so looking for suggestions or if anyone can think of ways to maybe help fix it as i'm really unsure.

Thanks

```
package TCPRequester;

import java.util.*;

public class AffdexArray {

private float valence = 0.0f;
private float previousValenceData = 0.0f;

int totalBuffer = 0;
int timerClicker = 0;
float valenceSum = 0f;
float valenceTotal = 0f;

private static final int FACEID_INDEX = 6;
private static final int VALENCE_INDEX = 17;   
ArrayList<Float> valenceArray;

public AffdexArray()
 {
    //the float and name needs to go above public method

    valenceArray = new ArrayList<Float>();

 }
    //change to if
    public void valenceArray(String[] inArray)
    {
        do{
            if(inArray[FACEID_INDEX].equals("1")){
                //this needs to be a repeatable process
                valence = Float.parseFloat(inArray[VALENCE_INDEX]);
                //places the valence value into an Array list
                valenceArray.add(valence);
                //adds 1 a click to every input into that buffer
                totalBuffer++;   
                timerClicker++;
            } else {
                timerClicker++;
            }
        } while(timerClicker <= 199);
        //timer array set up to make it go every 10 seconds.
            for(int i = 0; i<totalBuffer;i++)
                {           
                valenceSum += valenceArray.get(i);
                //add all values and divide by clicker amount. (mean?)
                }
            //after 10 seconds grab the values in buffer and clicker amount.
            valenceTotal = valenceSum / totalBuffer;
            //System.out.println("Valence Average = " + valenceTotal + "Previous Total: " + previousValenceData);      
            //Transfers float value into new variable
            previousValenceData = valenceTotal;
            //clear buffer and reset timer
            valenceArray.clear();
            totalBuffer = 0;
            timerClicker = 0;
            valenceTotal = 0;
    } 
}
```

Update - After breaking down and looking at the process with breakpoints.
When transferred into this class, the issue is coming from the array within the While do loop which is causing the issue and is filling  the array I was hoping would be full of 200 unique values but instead it’s filling it with the same value instead thus the 3 outputs a second instead of 1 every 20 seconds.

Is there a process to ensure it will pull a unique input every time it passes through the do while or is there a better practice to try?

Comment: you are simply iterating 200 times. how can you guarantee that every iteration happens exactly every 0.1 seconds? of course there are going to be lots of iterations putting duplicates into array because there are LOTS of iterations happening during 0.1 seconds, not just one

Comment: didn't you look at my answer below? You can do that by periodically putting the thread into sleep

Comment: I have commented the other to save multi stream conversations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking the advice of @mangusta, I went back and started allocating things to different threads and worked along with that idea.  After a bit of playing and activating timers I have got the calculations to work.

Thanks mangusta for the suggestions.

```
package TCPRequester;

import java.util.*;

public class AffdexArray
{

private float valence = 0.0f;
private float previousValenceData = 0.0f;

private static int totalBuffer = 0;
public static float valenceSum = 0f;
private static float valenceTotal = 0f;

private static final int FACEID_INDEX = 6;
private static final int VALENCE_INDEX = 17;   
public static ArrayList<Float> valenceArray; 

public AffdexArray()
{

    valenceArray = new ArrayList<Float>();    
    //initialise the timer to the earliest time in systems

}

void ValenceCalculation() throws InterruptedException
{  
    //Set timer for ten seconds then when it has passed, do system
    Timer mathsTimer = new Timer();
    TimerTask myTask = new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
        for(int i = 0; i<valenceArray.size();i++)
                {           
                valenceSum += valenceArray.get(i);
                //add all values and divide by clicker amount. (mean?)
                }
            //after 10 seconds grab the values in buffer and clicker amount.
            valenceTotal = valenceSum / totalBuffer;
            System.out.println("Valence Average = " + valenceTotal); 
            System.out.println("Data Count: " + valenceArray.size());;
            //Transfers float value into new variable
            //previousValenceData = valenceTotal;
            //clear buffer and reset timer
            valenceArray.clear();
            totalBuffer = 0;
            valenceSum = 0; 
        }
    };mathsTimer.schedule(myTask, 0, 5000);
}


public void valenceProcess(String[] inArray) 

{
    if(inArray[FACEID_INDEX].equals("1"))
    {
    //this needs to be a repeatable process

            valence = Float.parseFloat(inArray[VALENCE_INDEX]);
            //places the valence value into an Array list
            valenceArray.add(valence);
            //adds 1 a click to every input into that buffer
            totalBuffer++;   
            } else {
        } 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add delay to your counting in order to adjust to the necessary data arrival frequency (which is 10 records per 1 second, according to your words). However note that this method will miss arriving data if the frequency is more than 10Hz and will put duplicates if the frequency is less than 10Hz

```
public void valenceArray(String[] inArray) throws InterruptedException
{
   do{
        if(inArray[FACEID_INDEX].equals("1")){
            //this needs to be a repeatable process
            valence = Float.parseFloat(inArray[VALENCE_INDEX]);
            //places the valence value into an Array list
            valenceArray.add(valence);
            //adds 1 a click to every input into that buffer
            totalBuffer++;   
            timerClicker++;
        } else {
            timerClicker++;
        }

        Thread.sleep (100);
    } while(timerClicker <= 199);

//remaining part stays the same  
}
```

Regarding the remaining part, even though it is only about finding the average of at most 200 float numbers, it could possibly eat up a significant part of 0.1 sec interval and hence lead to a miss of incoming element, so it would be better to move that part outside into a separate thread for running in parallel with "valenceArray ()" method

Comment: @Bjsfreaked well it all depends on the way how the element "inArray[VALENCE_INDEX]" is filled. The new incoming element may be equal to the previous one on the next iteration, in that case of course there will be duplicates in "valenceArray". Do you want all elements in "valenceArray" to be unique?

Comment: The way suggested by me guarantees that there will be no more than 200 elements inserted into "valenceArray" during 20 seconds. It however does NOT guarantee that those elements will be all unique. If you want them to be unique, you may use Set <Float> to check every incoming element for uniqueness

Comment: I have tried the coding suggestion.  I am going to try and do your optimisation for multi threading as it may work more efficiently but to the thread sleep, the delay just slows the process but still fills with the same float input instead of pulling the data in the array which is always changing every .1 seconds but thank you for the input.  After playing around with the process more, i need to reformat my do while to work differently.

Comment: sorry, my laptop is acting weird so apologies for duplication or notification spam.  It can be equal but it should alternate as the value does regularly change from a value of -100 to 100.  The difference should at least change within a second as i'm purposely making the value change.  Currently I am limiting it to 200 inputs as with maths and input limitation, it *should* make an input for 18 seconds per full 200 array.  My issue is that the data is meant to change (as i am making it for testing) but all values from array 0 to 200 are the same number.

Comment: @Bjsfreaked in case if "inArray" is being changed by another thread, in makes sense to declare it as "volatile", so that your method may see the change of its contents - public void valenceArray(volatile String[] inArray)